# Organizing bundle in SF2

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, organization

I have to write a medium-sized web app with SF2 and I want to try to work properly with Bundles.

It's a good pratice to have, for example, a BlogBundle who is the "front-end" of the website (fetching posts, comments, categories, adding comments, etc ...), and a second bundle named AdminBundle with all the website administration (not only blog part, but all other) ? Or it's better to have a Blog Bundle with all the administration part inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no “hard” rules for that; I would recommend to apply the principle of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Im simple words:

- Try to logically cluster your application into categories of tasks.
- Determine the dependencies of these categories.
- Don't forget "internal" tasks.
- Create a bundle for each category.

In the end, you will maybe even have more than two or three bundles, but (depending on the complexity) 10 to 15.

Some bundles will provide functionality like background tasks, monitoring or statistics. Others will be for data management, then again you will have bundles for representation (customer and administration frontends, APIs).

If you put too much functionality into one bundle, it may become overly complex. And, imagine, if some day another developer joins you, it will be hard for them to start working on an isolated component, if it's too complex or has too many dependencies.